# Find keyword in a string and replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string where I'm trying to locate a keyword within that string and replace it. I've tried using `search()` which returns the position of the keyword. I have also tried using `replace("this is what i want to replace", $(this))`.

What i basically is trying to accomplish is this: I have the following yql-statement:

`$reCat = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'http://reddit.com/\'and xpath=\'//div[@class="drop-choices srdrop"]//a[@class="choice"]\'&format=json&callback=?';`

which gives me a list over the different /r/'s on reddit. When I click on one of them I want the one i clicked (e.g. http://reddit.com/r/askreddit) to replace the current url in my yql-statement.

Here's some not working attempts:

```
$('#cat1 > li > a').click(function(){
    var url = $reCat;
    var final = url.replace("http://reddit.com", $(this));
    $('#cat1').append('<li><a href="#">' + final + '</a></li>');
});
```

`$('#cat1 > li > a')` is where the category-list is placed. I'm just appending it to the list to see if my string changes, which it doesn't.

Another attempt:

```
$('#cat1 > li > a').click(function(){
    var reddit = 'http://reddit.com'
    var pos = $reCat.search(reddit);
    var url = $reCat;
    var result = [url.slice(0, pos), $(this), url.slice(pos)].join( '' );
    alert(result);
});
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: what are you trying to replace reddit.com with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that you are trying to use the `href` of `#cat1 > li > a` as the replacing value. If that is the case, just change your replace statement to

```
var final = url.replace("http://reddit.com", $(this).prop('href'));
```

You can also use `$(this).attr('href')`